# find the relationship of two vectors by coefficient of determination

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, statistics, correlation

I have a question about coefficient of  determination.

I need to find the relationship of two vectors.

Given two numerical vectors x and y, their determination of coefficient can be expressed as :

```
1 - ( 1 -  (dot_product(x,y))^2 / (|x|^2 + |y|^2)) / (1 - |y| * |y|/ ( y'dimension * |y|^2 ) ) 

|x|^2 = sum of squared of each element of vector x.
|y|  =  sum of each element of vector y.
```

Is that correct ?

I got the formula from some code but I do not know the authors.

How to understand  it?

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

From [wiki: Coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).

> In statistics, the coefficient of determination, denoted R2 and pronounced R squared, indicates how well data points fit a statistical model – sometimes simply a line or curve. It is a statistic used in the context of statistical models whose main purpose is either the prediction of future outcomes or the testing of hypotheses, on the basis of other related information. It provides a measure of how well observed outcomes are replicated by the model, as the proportion of total variation of outcomes explained by the model.[1
>   The correlation coefficient, **`r`**, and the coefficient of determination, **`r^2`**.

The mathematical formula for computing **`r`** is:

[image]

where `n` is the number of pairs of data.

---

References:

1. [wiki: Coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).
2. [Correlation Coefficient](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/Statistics2/correlation.htm).

Comment: this is not the same formula in my post. Thanks !